# Using underscore.js groupBy with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, underscore.js

Is it possible to use underscore's groupBy function with ember.js?

I have the following attempt which is obviously not working:

```
var activities = App.store.findMany(App.Activity, feed.mapProperty('id').uniq()) 
var grouped = _.groupBy(activities, function(activity){
  return activity.get('dateLabel;')
});
```

I get the following error:

> Object App.Activity has no method 'get'

The store is loaded with the correct data so findMany will not make a remote call.

The problem is that findMany returns a DS.ManyArray which is probably a lot different than what _.groupBy is looking for.

Comment: Underscore works with whatever objects are in the `activities` array. If these objects have no `get()` method then underscore has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I think the problem is that these are ember-data DS-ManyArray objects and are a lot different from what _.groupBy is looking for.

Comment: `_.groupBy()` has nothing to do with it at all. If you can do `activities[0].get('dateLabel')`, then will also be able to do `activity.get('dateLabel')` in the `groupBy()` callback.

Comment: that is my point, it has to be activities.objectAt(0)

Comment: Ah, I see. `_.groupBy()` can only iterate a native array, so you either must turn `activities` into a native array, or implement your own custom `groupBy()` function. That's not hard to do, see below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could implement your own `groupBy` function tailored for ember-data DS-ManyArray objects and extend `_` with it:

```
_.emberArrayGroupBy = function(emberArray, val) {
  var result = {}, key, value, i, l = emberArray.get('length'),
      iterator = _.isFunction(val) ? val : function(obj) { return obj.get(val); };

  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    value = emberArray.objectAt(i);
    key   = iterator(value, i);
    (result[key] || (result[key] = [])).push(value);
  }
  return result;
};
```

Now you can call

```
var grouped = _.emberArrayGroupBy(activities, function(activity) {
  return activity.get('dateLabel');
});
```

or more simply

```
var grouped = _.emberArrayGroupBy(activities, 'dateLabel');
```

---

The function above is based on underscore's original `groupBy()` implementation, which looks very similar:

```
_.groupBy = function(obj, val) {
  var result = {};
  var iterator = _.isFunction(val) ? val : function(obj) { return obj[val]; };
  each(obj, function(value, index) {
    var key = iterator(value, index);
    (result[key] || (result[key] = [])).push(value);
  });
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var activities = App.store.findMany(App.Activity, feed.mapProperty('id').uniq()) 
var grouped = _.groupBy(activities, function(activity){
  return activity.get('dateLabel;')
}).bind(this);
```

I did not run this code to test how it works but the idea is to 'bind' outer scope into inner closure function scope.
Hope this helps to get you some ideas...